# How do I use Nokogiri to parse a bit.ly stats page?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, bit.ly

I'm trying to parse the Twitter usernames from [a bit.ly stats page](http://bitly.com/U026ue+/global) using Nokogiri:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://bitly.com/U026ue+/global'))

twitter_accounts = []

shares = doc.xpath('//*[@id="tweets"]/li')

shares.map do |tweet|
  twitter_accounts << tweet.at_css('.conv.tweet.a')
end

puts twitter_accounts
```

My understanding is that Nokogiri will save `shares` in some form of tree structure, which I can use to drill down into, but my mileage is varying.

Comment: Are you sure that there are any tweets?  When I run the code above and inspect the document, I don't see any.

Comment: I'm seeing tweets Eric Walker.

Comment: You are misusing `map` in your `shares.map` loop. It should be `shares.each` instead.

Comment: Do you want to do this for any number of bitly stats pages, or just this one?

Comment: Mark, I'd like to be able to do this for any bitly page. Eric, I see tweets, but do let me know if that problem persists... weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Eric Walker was onto something. If you look at `doc`, the section where the tweets are supposed to be look like:

```
<h2>Tweets</h2>
  <ul id="tweets"></ul>
</div>
```

This is likely because they're generated by some JavaScript call which Nokogiri isn't executing. One possible solution is to use `watir` to traverse to the page, load the JavaScript and then save the HTML.

Here is a script that accomplishes just that. Note that you had some issues with your XPath arguments which I've since solved, and that watir will open a new browser every time you run this script:

```
require 'watir'
require 'nokogiri'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://bitly.com/U026ue+/global'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

twitter_accounts = []

shares = doc.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "tweet")]/a')

shares.each do |tweet|
  twitter_accounts << tweet.attr('title')
end

puts twitter_accounts
browser.close
```

You can also use [headless](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) to prevent a window from opening.

Answer (score 4):

That data is coming in from an Ajax request with a JSON response. It's pretty easy to get at though:

```
require 'json'
url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?_usragnt=Bitly&include_entities=true&rpp=100&q=nowness.com%2Fday%2F2012%2F12%2F6%2F2643'
hash = JSON.parse open(url).read
puts hash['results'].map{|x| x['from_user']}
```

I got that URL by loading the page in Chrome and then looking at the network panel, I also removed the timestamp and callback parameters just to clean things up a bit.

Comment: This is a smart fix, but I don't think there's a way from me to automatically retrieve that Ajax Request without manually looking it up in the Network Panel. Is that right? This works when you had require 'open-uri' :)

Comment: Sure. To construct the url in your script just look for the value of the q param (nowness...) in the original request and add it to the rest.